# Order dropdown by existing data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a list of records from a MySQL database. When a record is clicked it takes you to a page where you can update these records. I'm using a HTML form to display the data dynamically.

For example, if a game was released in `2007` I'd have a dropdown box with all the different years that it could be changed to.

My current SQL for the year dropdown is as follows;

```
SELECT DISTINCT gameYear FROM games ORDER BY gameYear
```

This displays the years in order. Is there a way to have them displayed in correct order (IE `2001, 2002, 2003` and so on) but have the existing year selected to begin with?

An example, a game with a year of `2007`.

When I click the record and go to edit the game, I want the dropdown box to display the current value (`2007`) automatically. Then, when I select the dropdown I want the years to still be in order.

Comment: What do you mean by `all the different years that it could be changed to`

Comment: If I want to edit the gameYear value, I have a dropdown box with all the different options that it could be changed to. I might want to change the gameYear from 2007 to 2001. I want the original year  (2007) to be automatically selected in the dropdown, yet display the other years in order too so they aren't all jumbled up.

Comment: SQL does not known anything about drop-downboxes and selected item. What language or system are you programming in?

Comment: I'm using PHP in my HTML form. I'm then using the SQL query to ORDER BY gameYear which displays them all in order. If I don't ORDER BY then the dropdown is displayed with the years in a random order.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to change order in such way. If you want to simply highlight one of the drop-down options, why not to use the "selected" attribute? Like <option value="2007" **selected**>2007</option>

Comment: The options aren't put in manually. They're generated dynamically through PHP and SQL from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it this way:

```
select DISTINCT gameYear from game order by 
  case
     when gameYear = 2007 then 0
     else gameYear 
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably fill the dropdown by looping over your SQL result set and output HTML `<option>` elements. You need to check inside this loop if the current loop value is equal to the year of your game. If it is add the `selected` HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedYear  is Your  current Selected Year

```
SELECT '$SelectedYear' as gameYear
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT gameYear from game 
  WHERE gameYear <> $SelectedYear 
  ORDER BY gameYear)
```